# Extraer el mínimo valor entre variables de diferentes datos

Tags: python, string, lista

Lo que sucede es que tengo un grupo de variables entre números y textos o strings.

Tengo que hallar el mínimo valor de número entre todas ellas, pero al haber textos tengo el siguiente error: ***TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'.***

Si x > 5, no tengo ningún problema porque todas mis variables son números y se imprime el menor de todas ellas, pero si x < 5, para este ejemplo x = 4, entonces sí que tengo problema.

```
jornales = [1566,1154,'No Aplica']

for i in range(len(jornales)):

    x = 4    
    seguro_1 = jornales[0]
    seguro_2 = jornales[1]

    if x > 5:
        seguro_3 = 4568

    else:
        seguro_3 = jornales[2]

    general = min(seguro_1, seguro_2, seguro_3)

    print(f"{i+1:02} {general:>20}")
```

En **excel** por ejemplo yo puedo hallar el mínimo de un conjunto de números y textos **y simplemente a los textos me los ignora y coge el mínimo valor**, ¿hay alguna forma en python?

Saludos cordiales.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si como das a entender solo tienes tres items y el tercero es una cadena solo cuando `x < 5`  tu problema es simplemente que aplicas mal el condicional, no sería  `if x > 5:` sino  `if x < 5:`

```
jornales = [1566, 1154, 'No Aplica']    
x = 4

if x > 5:
    minimo = min(jornales)
else:
    minimo = min((*jornales[:2], 4568))

print(minimo)
```

Para una opción más genérica, puedes filtrar solo los valores numéricos  de tu lista con `isinstance` y `numbers.Number` como clase base. Esto filtrará no solo `int`, también `float`, `decimal.Decimal`, `complex`, `fractions.Fraction` y cualquier tipo propio que derive e las clase abstracta.

Si no vas a necesitar el filtro nada más que para generar el mínimo, usa un generador para no tener que crear un contenedor en memoria con los valores que pasan el filtro:

```
import numbers

jornales = [1566, 1154, 'No Aplica', 4.52, 251]
minimo = min((item for item in jornales if isinstance(item, numbers.Number)))
```

> ```
> >>> minimo
> 4.25
> ```

Con otros tipos:

```
import numbers
from fractions import Fraction
from decimal import Decimal


jornales = [1566, 1154, 'No Aplica', 4.52, 251, Fraction(1.5), Decimal(2.3)]

minimo = min((item for item in jornales if isinstance(item, numbers.Number)))
```

> ```
> >>> minimo
> Fraction(3, 2)
> ```

Tendrás una excepción si hay un complejo (`complex`) en el contenedor como cabe esperar. Se podría también filtrar dado el caso.

Otra posibilidad es implementar la función `min` por nosotros mismos para que "ignore" objetos no comparables entre si:

```
def min_value(iterable):
    if not len(iterable):
        raise ValueError("min_value() arg is an empty sequence")   
    minimo = float("inf")
    for n in iterable:
        try:
            if n < minimo:
                minimo = n
        except TypeError:
            pass
    return minimo
```

> ```
> >>> jornales = [1566, 1154,'No Aplica']
> >>> min_value(jornales)
> 1154
> ```

Comment: Muchas gracias por sus planteamientos @FJSevilla, en mi caso lo uso para generar el mínimo. Saludos coridales.

Answer (score 2):

Si lo único que te interesan son los valores de tipo *int* y no los de tipo *string*, puedes **crear un nuevo array** que ignore estos últimos y solamente guarde los valores de tipo *int* para posteriormente, obtener el mínimo de todos ellos. Una manera sencilla de hacerlo sería:

```
jornales = [1566,1154,'No Aplica']

int_values = [i for i in jornales if isinstance(i, int)]

min_int_value = min(int_values)
```

El resultado del nuevo array es **[1566, 1154]**:

```
print(int_values)
```

Y si imprimos el valor mínimo, nos proporciona **1154** :

```
print(min(int_values))
```